# Unable to bind to locking port 70 54 within 45000 ms

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to run my selenium test using MVN test command line. Curiously, I tried it 3 days ago and it ran successfully:

```
------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running GoogleNavigationTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 45.672 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

   Failed tests:   testApp(GoogleNavigationTest): Unable to bind to locking port 70
   54 within 45000 ms

  Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Here's my test:

```
import java.util.List;

 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GoogleNavigationTest {
@Test
public void testApp(){
    // The Firefox driver supports javascript 
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // Go to the Google Suggest home page
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");

    // Enter the query string "Cheese"
    WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    query.sendKeys("Cheese");

    // Sleep until the div we want is visible or 5 seconds is over
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
        WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_e"));

        // If results have been returned, the results are displayed in a drop down.
        if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
          break;
        }
    }

    // And now list the suggestions
    List<WebElement> allSuggestions =   
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='gssb_a gbqfsf']"));

    for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions) {
        System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
    }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Hv u verified whether theres sumtin runnin on port7054.  Also if u r not using some specific firefoxprofile, then there's no need of creatin new ff profile.

Comment: What version of Firefox do you have? What version of Selenium do you have?

Comment: i didn't create any firefox profile

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just used the chromeDriver and it works fine .

Answer (score 4):

Late reply, but try this updated code. Selenium Webdriver binds the instance to a specific TCP port. In the case your test fails and the driver is not properly closed, the port will be held on to for x amount of time.  Using driver.Quit() will generally free up the TCP port.

To test to see which port might currently still be held on to, you can use the netstat -a command (windows) to find the list of active connections.

A way to get around / side step this issue, is allow selenium to bind to another port that is generated by your code. Most ports above 7000 to 7100 are fine to use. Selenium's built in way to handle the ports is to initially try to bind to 7055, if that fails, bind to 7054, if that fails bind to 7056.  In MOST test cases this is fine, but I have found that multiple tests still encounter failure. So instead of using the defaults, specify your own to the profile.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GoogleNavigationTest {
@Test
public void testApp(){

    // Specify a new or randomly generated port for the driver to use
    int genPort = 7052;
    // The Firefox driver supports javascript 
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    //In the profile, assign it a different port to use instead of 7054,7055,7056
    //In my tests, I have a method that will generate a port to use that is open
    firefoxProfile.Port = genPort; 
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Edit: Diving deeper into this issue has revealed that two things contribute to this error.  The first being the TCP / UDP Port selection on your local machine, the second being the amount of time that selenium must copy the base firefox profile from the drive to it's temp folder.  The slower the transfer, the more likely it is to have the port binding issue.

To break down the issue, make your profile as small as possible.  This can involve deleting some base firefox files that are generated upon startup. My firefox profile is > 5 MB in size.  Before I did this research my profile size was over 60 MB. At the start of each test, it would try to transfer 60MB to a temp location and bind to a locking port.

My new code hasnt failed me

```
    var smallerProfile = @"C:\Firefox Profiles\SmallProfile";
    var genPort = new Random(); 

     FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(smallerProfile);
     profile.Clean();
     profile.Port = genPort.Next(7000, 7500);
```

I copy over the smaller profile at the start of each main run.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium v2.21 does not support Firefox 17. In fact, Firefox 17 is only supported with version v2.27 which was released a couple of days ago.

Either downgrade Firefox or update Selenium.

May or may not be the reason for this particular error, but you *must* do one of the above to even have half a chance of getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/selenium-users/i5NjiNkRJaY)

Its because of the more than one javaw.exe is running in the background.
To view this Goto task manager and choose the processes tab.
You can see that there will be more than one javaw.exe is running.
Select the process javaw.exe one by one and click "End process" and Try running the script again.