# Launch Google through Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Code is:

```
package heycare;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestScript1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6b', time: '2013-08-12 15:43:19'
System info: os.name: 'Windows NT (unknown)', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:98)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:251)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at heycare.TestScript1.main(TestScript1.java:10)
```

I am able to launch Firefox but not Google through this code. What can be the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver unable to bind to locking port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957015/selenium-webdriver-unable-to-bind-to-locking-port)

Comment: Every time I've seen this error, it's been because the version of Selenium I'm using doesn't support the version of Firefox. The browser opens, but you can't interact with it.

Comment: What version of windows are you using ?

Comment: Current Version 50.1.0 Selenium Version 2.35. If you know the correct version of firefox then please give me the link. I am new to selenium.
Today i got this error:-org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
s\\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.5","st":1481246673000},"firefox@getpocket.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla