# Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms

Tags: vba, excel, firefox, selenium

I get this error 100% of the time when I try to run the following Excel VBA code:

```
Sub Try()
    Dim selenium As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

    selenium.Start "firefox", "http://www.google.com"
End Sub
```

I am running:

1. Windows 7 with all updates
2. Firefox 38.01 (latest)
3. Excel 2010 with all updates
4. Selenium wrapper. (If I update to the latest Selenium version I get the same message except on port 9054)

This even happens immediately after a reboot.

I have disabled BitDefender and Windows firewall and that does not help.

Comment: See if [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140865/unable-to-bind-to-locking-port-7054-within-45000-ms) or [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803605/unable-to-bind-to-locking-port-70-54-within-45000-ms) helps? Else you have [THIS](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=unable+to+bind+to+locking+port+7054+within+45000+ms+selenium) :D

Comment: Seems more like a firefox issue. I was able to make it work with Chrome without any trouble. On my pc, if I try with FF, it simply crashes. I am using latest versions of FF(38.0.1) and Selenium (v1.0.23.0) on win 8.1 64 bit (office 2010 32 bit). What happens if you try `selenium.Start "chrome", "http://www.google.com"`

Comment: When I try to use chrome I get the following long error message from VBA:  
Run­time error '­2146233088 (80131500)':

Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to 
the remote server ­­­> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A 
connection attempt failed because the connected party did not 
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection 
failed because connected host has failed to respond 120.0.0.1:49415
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint 
endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

Comment: Do you have the latest .Net Framework?

Comment: Yes, I have .net  4.5.1

Comment: none of the above links helped you? Unfortunatley, my expertise doesn't include Selenium else I would have posted an answer. :) All that I can say is that; for me it works for chrome and fails for ff

Comment: I did see & read the above links before I posted the question.